# Chrome top bar (URL) is ruining my design

Tags: javascript, html, css

as I am going ahead with the journey of learning web dev, more and more questions pop out. Like this one:

I am currently learning JS and as I grasp new knowledge, I build small apps like the one you'll see in the photos and the snippet.

**The point is**:

I always build these mini apps and websites with mobile-first approach, mainly because I want to share them with my friends and I don't want to deal with media queries. I noticed that the preview I get from the mobile simulator in Chrome is way different than what I get on my actual smarthphone, at least when it comes to the height. Let me explain...

This problem becomes more obvious and annoing when I build these little apps which I want to appear like native android or apple apps, so no scrolling, only the viewport height.

**A mini app I recently built - ON CHROME MOBILE SIMULATOR** which in the beggining it was both vertically and horizontally centered, but I had to move it up, otherwise on my physical device I would had to scroll to see it all

[image: Screenshot of Chrome mobile simulator]

**The result - ON MY SMARTPHONE**

[image: Screenshot of my smartphone]

I would've expect that the top bar would just push down the content and I would just have to take its height into consideration in order to have a "native app" look (no scrolling), but it looks like it kinda cuts part of the background.

How can I take this bar into consideration and have a predictable result?

**Here the snippet of the app**

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let clear = document.querySelector('.clear')
let message = document.querySelector('.message')
let first = document.querySelector('.first')
let second = document.querySelector('.second')
let third = document.querySelector('.third')
let fourth = document.querySelector('.fourth')
let fifth = document.querySelector('.fifth')
let sixth = document.querySelector('.sixth')

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  first.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)
  second.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)
  third.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)
  fourth.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)
  fifth.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)
  sixth.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1)

  message.classList.add('show')

  button.disabled = true

  setTimeout(function(){
    button.disabled = false
    message.classList.remove('show')
  }, 1000 * 3) 

})


clear.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  first.innerText = ''
  second.innerText = ''
  third.innerText = ''
  fourth.innerText = ''
  fifth.innerText = ''
  sixth.innerText = ''
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url('conf.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position-x: right;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.container {
  width: 95vw;
  height: 420px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.title {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: verdana;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.tenta {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.numbers {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.number {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: black;
}

.button {
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  transition: .2s linear;
  outline: none;
  background: rgb(0,255,117)
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.clear {
  padding: .2em .5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  transition: .2s linear;
  outline: none;
}

.clear:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(450px + 20vw);
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: none;
}

p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Number Generator</h1>
        <h3 class="nonsai">Non sai quali numeri giocare?</h3>
        <h3 class="tenta">Tenta la fortuna con l'algoritmo di<br> Number Generator!</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="numbers">
        <div class="first number"></div>
        <div class="second number"></div>
        <div class="third number"></div>
        <div class="fourth number"></div>
        <div class="fifth number"></div>
        <div class="sixth number"></div>
      </div>

      <button class="button">Genera Numeri</button>
      <button class="clear">Refresh</button>

    </div>
    <p class="message">Puoi usare Number Generator una volta ogni ora</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are facing is brought about by mobile Chrome (and Safari) having set vh to be a fixed unit. That is, you aren’t really getting the full vertical height when there has been no scrolling so something positioned at the bottom of the page is cut off.

The decision to do this was taken to prevent an uncomfortable jump when the user scrolled down and the browser bar disappeared. It makes things difficult for the sort of web app you are creating.

There is quite a bit of discussion about this on the web see for example a recent article at [https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/[https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/][1]](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/%5Bhttps://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/%5D%5B1%5D) which touches on workarounds with JavaScript.

I am sorry I cannot create a snippet to illustrate this but I’m confined to a touch device and SO doesn’t allow snippet creation from those!

Comment: No problem, thank you very much, I'll take a look at the article!

Comment: Yep, I simply changed 100vh to 100% and my page isn't scrolling. What a stupid error!!! (From me of course...)